# SQL Server job command line

Tags: ssis

I have created couple of jobs on SQL SERVER out of SSIS packages , i can see command line for some of them start with /DTS and for some /SQL , even though all jobs creates in same version and perform data load operation only.
What is the difference between these options?

Answer (score 2):

These options indicate the location where the package is stored. /SQL indicates the packages is stored in the msdb database and /DTS indicates the package is stored in the SSIS Package Store.

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017#parameter) for more information.